# Android App - Does Google Play Developer Console allow you to downgrade your minSDKVersion

Tags: android, google-play

I want to know suppose I upload a new app on Google Play with `minSDKVersion` to 14 with Version 1 and then later I want to make it compatible to Android 2.3+ so I will set the `minSDKVersion` to 9 in Version 1.1

Is this possible or Google Play does not allow you to decrese the value of `minSDKVersion` in updates release ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @Squonk I can't take risk..if anyone tried that would be good if they share

Comment: There is no risk - either the developer console will allow you to upload it or it will throw an error when you try to upload and tell you if it isn't allowed.

Comment: @Squonk If it won't allow later then it can make me in trouble if I later target users of Android 2.3+ also

Comment: As far as I remember, there is an app that previously supported until Android 2.2, but then suddenly changed to minimum Android 4.0. (I forgot the name). So I believe it's possible. Edit: oops, I misread your question, but I believe the logic is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible.All you have to do is increment your **app's version code**.

Comment: so Google Play allow you to increase or decrease the minSDKLevel at anytime. right ? Do you have doc link for this

Comment: i had done this on my app previously. Havent you seen apps launched with minSdk 14 and extends its support to minSdk 9 later on.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you dont need to do anything in google play developer console, just modify the minSDKVersion in the manifest and use a higher version code

Comment: so Google Play allow you to increase or decrease the minSDKLevel at anytime. right ? Do you have doc link for this

Comment: Google play takes the min version from your manifest, you dont put min version info anywhere else but in the manifest. There is no documentation about it because it is considered a development issue, not a publishing one.
 
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html

Comment: If you're too paranoid and have some time upload some other apk then try to lower his minsdkversion and reupload it, so you check by yourself :)